# Copy IIS site folder to other drive with permissions intact

Tags: windows, iis

I have an IIS application in `wwwroot\AppFolder` which I want to copy to a another drive before making some changes. Some folders under the AppFolder require manual configuration of permissions, such as adding write access for IIS_IUSR to an OpLogs folder etc.

In order to quickly revert the IIS Application in case something goes wrong, I want to create a copy with these permissions intact (the ones accessible from folder properties/security tab). Using `xcopy` as suggested [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/696004/copying-a-directory-by-retaining-its-permission) does not work if I copy `AppFolder` to another drive on the server.

Lots of documentation I read suggests `/x` and `/o` flags should do what I'm trying to do, but they don't work in my case. How do I copy the IIS application folder to another drive without losing the permission settings?

**Update**: I noticed that even though the permissions of the folders no longer contain some of the entries when they're copied to their destination with `xcopy` , if I copy them back to their original directory, again using `xcopy` with the above parameters, then the permission appears again! For example `Network Service` having access to the folder. So whatever is going on here, it is leading to permissions not being available in the destination directory, but somehow kept around as metadata. So as long as I use `xcopy` for the roundtrip, my problem goes away. I also checked what happens if I copy to the same folder (wwwroot) via regular copy && paste (using the mouse) and permissions are not kept in that case, so regardless of the destination, `xcopy` is the way to go.

This does not change the fact that I don't understand how the permissions are disappearing and appearing again.

Comment: I know its not what you are asking for, but have you considered using virtual directories and virtual applications to include directories outside of wwwroot to your website? on my iis servers, i keep the applications in their own directory on D, and then use a virtual application to map it to a location in the site. so d:\webs\app1\v1 maps to www.server.com/app1/ . then when v2 comes out, you just drop it in d:\webs\app1, and repoint the virtual application to the v2 folder. that way you can keep your backups in the app folder, and use inherited permissions so they are always right.

Comment: also consider why your permissions are so complicated. an applications executing user should never have write access to a location within the application path. instead write/configure the application to write to a directory outside of the application path.

Comment: Thanks, Frank Thomas. It is the age old scenario: I inherited something with a large, enterprise deployment base and I'm trying to improve things one step at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I copy the IIS application folder to another drive without losing the permission settings?

Use `robocopy` with the `/SEC` option:

> `/SEC` : Copy files with SECurity (equivalent to `/COPY:DATS`).

Where:

> (copyflags :
>
> - D=Data,
> - A=Attributes,
> - T=Timestamps,
> - S=Security=NTFS ACLs,
> - O=Owner info, U=aUditing info)
> - File Data (D) always includes file Timestamps (T).

Source: [Robocopy "Robust File Copy" - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)